# Can a large power supply cause overheating?

Tags: power-supply, fan, cooling, overheating

I have a laptop which is just over one year old, and ever since I have had it, there have been some very serious overheating problems. The fan is almost always at full blast, which is incredibly loud, and if I place my finger on the bottom of the laptop near the fan, it becomes too hot to touch after about 2 seconds. And often, when I play games even on modest graphics settings, my machine turns of automatically halfway through the game, presumably due to overheating.

This is very worrying for me, because my laptop is not doing any intensive processing at all. In fact, right now, all I have running is my Chrome web browser with a single tab. My CPU is running at about 1%, my memory at about 8%, and I have run various checks to make sure there is nothing intensive running in the background. But right now my machine is very hot, and the fan is very loud.

The rest of my machine is: Intel i7 2.9 GHz, 32 GB RAM, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 880M, and running Windows 8. Now, the one thing that I can think of is my power supply, which is very large: 180 W. This was a custom specification machine, and I chose a high-capacity power supply because I sometimes perform very computationally-expensive GPU-based processing for work. However, I would have thought that a large power supply only draws a large amount of power when necessary -- and the rest of the time it will only draw a modest amount. Therefore, when my machine is virtually idle (such as right now), it shouldn't be drawing that much power, and hence my machine shouldn't be overheating...

So given all this: **Is it likely that the cause of my overheating is my very large power supply?**

Comment: If the power supply is the right voltage and not defective, a higher-than-needed capacity should not be the cause of overheating.  The power supply voltage can be verified by measuring it, and running on the battery could provide an indication of whether the power supply is the source of overheating.

Comment: Make and specific model of Laptop would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

If the power supply is the correct voltage and is not broken, it is not the problem. The capacity of the power supply does not matter, so long as it is sufficient.

The overheating problem is likely due to dust, fan problems, or other mechanical issues with the heatsink and fan.